# Sigma and Pi Chemistry/Math Permutation Question

Tags: finite-groups, chemistry

Does anyone know if sigma and pi bonds in chemistry have any mathematical definition? The reason I'm asking this is because I've recently read a lot about cycles and permutations, and they seem to primarily use sigma and pi in their notation when multiplying 2 separate cycles. Just a heads up, it might not even be related and was just curious.

Comment: They're not related. It's just that $\pi$ and $\sigma$ are convenient Greek letters.

Comment: I would guess that is the case. That makes sense.

Comment: Not at all related. The same symbol may have different meanings in the same subject, let alone different subjects.

Comment: Interestingly, both chemistry and group theory have a notion of "conjugation", which as far as I know is also coincidental.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I knew is that the $\sigma$-bond involves either $sp$, $sp^2$ or $sp^3$ hybridization whereas $\pi$-bond involves overlapping of $p$-orbitals.  May refer to [LCAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_combination_of_atomic_orbitals).

Comment: [This](https://courses.cit.cornell.edu/mse5470/handout8.pdf) may also be helpful.